# osmnx boundaries and admin_level

Tags: openstreetmap, levels, boundaries

I hope someone here can help me to retrieve the correct administration level(s) from OSM. I am using the following code, but admin_level seems to be ignored:

```
tags = {"boundary":"administrative","admin_level":"4" }
gdf =ox.geometries.geometries_from_bbox(51.5, 51.0, 11.7, 11.2, tags)
gdf.shape
```

The bounding box seems to be used as a polygon to create an intersection with all the boundaries in the OSM database, the first tag is working because only administrative boundaries are returned, but the filter on level is ignored (gdf["admin_level"].head() shows level 6).

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong, and how I can use this package better; it seems like a very useful library.
Thanks,
Gijs

Result using the bounding box:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

OK, rereading the documentation again made me realize that osmnx is using [OR] statements and not [AND] statements as I was presuming; removing the boundary request from the query is indeed giving only admin_level:4 results.

tags (dict) – Dict of tags used for finding objects in the selected area. Results returned are the union, not the intersection of each individual tag.

Some additional code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw840.png